# Gradient descent rule in neural network (R)

Tags: gradient

I am getting confused about the package "neuralnet". 
I want to know the gradient descent rule used in neuralnet(R).

delta w(t) = -n(dE/dw) + u(delta w(t-1))
where E = error, w = weight, u is momentum, n = learning rate and t = time

Is that correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.